# How To Create Dynamic Hyperlinks Between Parents and Child Page in PHP

Tags: php

Can you please help me to figure it out how I can create dynamic links between PHP parent and child pages

in my case I have a 4 pages like

```
category.php
subCat.php
products.php
single.php
```

with a database structure like this:

[image]

A Category has one to Many relationship with subCat
A subCat has one to Many relationship with Products
A Products has one to Many relationship with single

Now I would like to know how I can make a link from category.php to each slected subCat.php

```
<?php
echo '<a href="url">Comedy</a>';
```

and so on?
Thanks

Comment: there are multiple ways of producing your solution, forming highly opinion based answers. What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks iam for replying . what I am hoping to understand is creating a simple cms in a way that WordPress works. I am not sure how it wouldbe possible?1

Comment: wordpress relies fairly heavily on the use of url querystrings and post querystrings to move data and actions from page `a` to page `b`, a decent solution is to turn each step's link into a url containing a url querystring of the ID that was clicked. using your example your url would be similar to `url/subCat.php?id=3` where id `3` corresponds to the `comedy` subcategory in your database, from there you would generate links to follow that pattern into your `products` and `single`

Comment: Thanks iam but can you please let me know how to use the data in page b? I mean I got you point sending the data but how to read them on page B?

Comment: use `$_GET['id']` it will return the `id` value in the querystring and you can use that to make a database call and retrieve all the `products` under that `subCat`